# Ember Computed on Array Object

Tags: ember.js

Is it currently possible to use Ember.computed properties on objects properties in an array.

```
goalOneActive: Ember.computed.notEmpty('goals.[0].name')
```

Comment: Of course as soon as I post the question I figure out the answer. Thanks coffee. The correct syntax is 

    Ember.computed.notEmpty('goals.0.name')

Comment: Good job answering your own question! Consider posting your comment as an answer instead of a comment so that there's an official answer and also for more visibility.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  It's OK to answer your own question- In doing so, it improves the body of knowledge in StackOverflow that could help others with your same problem.

Comment: Thanks. SO wouldn't let me accept it so quickly after posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
Ember.computed.notEmpty('goals.0.name')
```